# Something better for this situation than using IF?

Tags: sql-server-2008, if-statement

I am writing queries that are used on a website. When the query is needed it gets directly parsed to the server and the outcome is all controlled by the query. The website just returns the table. What I do have on the site is checkboxes that the client can select and those get parsed into the query as either `@var = 1` or `@var = 0`. Because of that, right now I have this code to check and add or not depending if it is checked. My question is, is there a better way to go about this than using the `IF` statement like this as I have several sections of the code that include this:

```
SET @sql = 'select distinct '
If @mgchk = 1 
    SET @sql = @sql + 'p.MainGroup'
If @sgchk = 1 and @sql = 'select distinct '
    SET @sql = @sql + 'p.SubGroup'
If @sgchk = 1 and @sql not like '%SubGroup'
    SET @sql = @sql + ',p.SubGroup'
If @ssgchk = 1 and @sql = 'select distinct '
    SET @sql = @sql + 'p.SubSubGroup'
If @ssgchk = 1 and @sql not like '%SubSubGroup'
    SET @sql = @sql + ',p.SubSubGroup'
If @Seasonchk = 1 and @sql = 'select distinct '
    SET @sql = @sql + 'p.Season'
If @Seasonchk = 1 and @sql not like '%Season'
    SET @sql = @sql + ',p.Season'
If @vendorchk = 1 and @sql = 'select distinct '
    SET @sql = @sql + 'p.VendorID'
If @vendorchk = 1 and @sql not like '%VendorID'
    SET @sql = @sql + ',p.VendorID'

SET @sql = 
    @sql + 
    ' into 
        ##aa 
    from 
        RPProducts p, 
        RPIv i, 
        RPTrsd d, 
        RPTrs s 
    WHERE 
    s.StoreID = d.StoreID and 
        s.ReceiptNO = d.ReceiptNO and 
        i.UPC = d.UPC and 
        i.StoreID = d.StoreID and 
        i.IVProduct = p.Productid and 
        s.TRSdate >= '''+ convert(varchar(10), @trsfrom, 101) +''' and 
        s.TRSdate <= '''+ convert(varchar(10), @trsto, 101) +''''
execute sp_executesql @sql
```

@mgchk / @sgchk / @ssgchk / @seasonchk / @vendorchk are the checkboxes variables

To answer @Aaron,

Global temp because of the dynamic queries. The whole query gets processed and drop right away when the data is pulled. No clash will happen there.

My date variables are `datetime` and it gives me an error within dynamic SQL.

Yes, recalling the same thing over to check, which is the reason for this whole question, if there is something better to use than the `IF` checking.

And I find using alias joins easier...

Comment: Oh wow, so many things to pick on here ... global ##temp table, why? Dates as regional strings, why? Checking over and over again if the column you're adding is the first one, why? Old-style joins, why?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - updated post with answers

Comment: Have you tried letting two users run this stored procedure at the same time? About what you call "alias joins" - [please read this IN FULL, including the comments](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx).

Comment: @Aaron - Have read the article, and greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-- rather than convert to a dangerously formatted string,
-- here is a much better way to strip time from a datetime
-- (if you need to!)

SET @trsfrom = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @trsfrom), 0);
SET @trsto = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @trsto), 0);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT DISTINCT ';

-- here's an easier way to strip the first comma:

SET @sql += SUBSTRING(
    CASE WHEN @mgchk     = 1 THEN ',p.MainGroup'   ELSE '' END
  + CASE WHEN @sgchk     = 1 THEN ',p.SubGroup'    ELSE '' END
  + CASE WHEN @ssgchk    = 1 THEN ',p.SubSubGroup' ELSE '' END
  + CASE WHEN @Seasonchk = 1 THEN ',p.Season'      ELSE '' END
  + CASE WHEN @vendorchk = 1 THEN ',p.VendorID'    ELSE '' END, 2, 2000);

SET @sql += ' INTO ##aa 
    FROM
      dbo.RPProducts AS p -- use schema prefix!
    INNER JOIN dbo.RPIv AS i  -- use PROPER JOINS!
      ON i.IVProduct = p.Productid
    INNER JOIN dbo.RPTrsd AS d 
      ON i.UPC = d.UPC 
      AND i.StoreID = d.StoreID
    INNER JOIN dbo.RPTrs AS s 
      ON s.StoreID = d.StoreID 
      AND s.ReceiptNO = d.ReceiptNO
    WHERE s.TRSdate >= @trsfrom -- use strongly typed parameters!
    AND s.TRSdate <= @trsto;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
    N'@trsfrom DATETIME, @trsto DATETIME', 
    @trsfrom, @trsto;
----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ here is how the query gets the @trsfrom & @trsto values
```

I still think your use of a ##global temp table is quite dangerous. If two people run this code at the same time, they are going to have serious problems.

Comment: I am not trying to argue you are wrong. I have been working with MsSQL only for past 2 months so I am still trying to learn the rights and wrongs and kick the bad habits. Your Answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Just have few questions. The user selects a date on the website which gets parsed in as datetime, where does the query see this information? in the declare what does the N' do? and in the CASE WHEN what does the  2, 2000 represent? Again, thank you so much

Comment: @JohnZ I marked in the code how the datetime parameters are passed into the query. You don't need to convert to string and concatenate to pass literals in (depending on how they are used) - much safer to pass them as parameters to sp_executesql ([more on this here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)). The `N` prefix denotes that the contained string is Unicode, and sp_executesql requires Unicode values. The `2, 2000` means "start from the 2nd character and take 2000 characters" - this strips the leading comma.

Comment: You Sir, are an amazing person to help me as such. I am bookmarking your site and will be reading up and hopefully learning from there. One last question in regards to your code so I understand what it does and what I can change `DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @trsto), 0)` the `DAY` and `0` do what?

Comment: Also is this code SQL Server 2005 compliant? As some of the clients we have still use 2005?